# Some notifications are not showing for Empathy

Tags: 11.10, gnome, empathy

I am on Ubuntu 11.10 and using Gnome Shell.

Since installation I am noticing that when my contacts Signs In or Signs Out, there is no notification showing at Gnome Shell. The sound notification works though. I am getting the sound but no visual notification.

At Unity it is working well. The problem seems to be Gnome Shell specific.

Does anyone else faced similar issue?

Comment: I have a similar issue where I get a sound notification but not visual for all Empathy notifications. I'm using Unity.

Comment: Suggest bug report

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).